# Where is the hyperlink in the word document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to make a list of hyperlinks and append the location inside the document of each hyperlink,  and if possible the position inside the page (line number?)

> e.g. https://stackoverflow.com ........... Page 234 Line 58

I know how to get the hyperlinks from the Document object

```
Dim objDoc As Document
Dim i As Integer
Set objDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=sUri)
For i = 1 To objDoc.Hyperlinks.Count
     debug.print objDoc.Hyperlinks(i).Address
next i
```

but I cannot find a property that tells me where the link is in the document. Any idea?

Comment: [`Hyperlink.Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.hyperlink.range)?

Comment: if I print objDoc.Hyperlinks(i).Range, it gives me the same thing as objDoc.Hyperlinks(i).TexttoDisplay, i.e. the content of the doc where the link is. Is there another way to use the range to find the location?

Comment: May be this [link1](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=59) and  [link2](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/10300246/Word-VBA-How-to-get-an-ABSOLUTE-line-number.html) help.

Comment: @Ahmed AU thanks, that gave me the information I needed

Comment: Hyperlink is a field.  You access the code and result for the link separately as .Code.Text and .Result.Text respectively.   If you want the range of the hyperlink then that is what is returned by the .result property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @ahmed-au links, I found that the following gave me the page number:

```
objDoc.Hyperlinks(i).Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
```

and the line number:

```
objDoc.Hyperlinks(i).Range.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)
```

The codes to use to get the various informations about the range selected are on this Microsoft page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/word.wdinformation